# 3-Column Layout -- Without Columns

Tags: css

How do you code a three-column layout in CSS when the source order jumps around from column to column?

The page has seven sections -- [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hpr2b/4/) shows how the required source order compares to the layout. The **number** is for its position in the source order and the **text** is where it should appear on the page.

http://jsfiddle.net/hpr2b/4/

[image: jsfiddle screen cap in chrome]

As you can see, there are essentially three columns and three rows, but the elements in the second row shouldn't top-align and the second row shouldn't clear the first row. Each section should be flush with the bottom of the section that is located above it.

**Notes:**

- The source order matches the order that the elements need to appear on mobile devices and unfortunately cannot be changed
- I also don't have the option of duplicating sections in the markup and then showing/hiding them based on viewport width
- Absolute positioning is unfortunately not an option because the layout must adapt to any viewport width 320px and up

I've tried a number of well-known CSS layout techniques and the above fiddle shows the most successful attempt -- here is the code used for the "top row":

```
.top-center {
    float: left;
    width: 55%;
    margin-left: 25%;
}

.top-left {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    margin-left: -80%;
}

.top-right {
    float: right;
    width: 20%;
}
```

Here are the problems I'm encountering:

1. IE 9/10 is a complete mess (see below)
2. In Chrome, the "Middle Right" div always clears the "Top Left" div, preventing it from being positioned beneath "Top Right". Also, if the "Top Right" div becomes too tall, it overlaps "Middle Right".
3. In Firefox, the second "row" top aligns, overlapping the left and right sections of the first row.

Here is what it looks like in IE10:

[image: jsfiddle screen cap in IE10]

And here it is in Firefox:

[image: jsfiddle screen cap in Firefox]

Comment: May i ask if you have <!DOCTYPE html> at the top of your html document. That can sometimes fix it in IE.

Comment: If you have that sort of layout requirement, why don;t you just change to order of the output source, or consider using absolute positioning?

Comment: Mike - The source order matches the order the elements need to appear on mobile devices and unfortunately can't be changed. I added a note on this in the question, thanks for reminding me

Comment: user2067005: yes, and I made sure everything validates as well

Comment: Do you only have 9 items?  As suggested above, consider using absolute positioning.

Comment: Absolute positioning is not a good solution at all, because he mentions in needs to work on mobile devices and scale.

Comment: Is the order of the elements completely out of your control or chosen purely for the mobile browser (the distinction here is important)?

Comment: cimmanon - the source order was chosen for mobile and I do have access to the markup; thanks for commenting, I refer to your Stack answers often

Comment: What does the mobile version of the layout look like? Is it a one-column scenario in the order that the elements are given in the source code?

Comment: Marc - yes that's correct, the sections are more or less stacked one after the other

Answer (score 1):

If the positioning is that important and you cannot control the (order of the) HTML code (I assume so from reading your question), I would rather go for having a somewhat usable absolute positioning using CSS, and refine it (onDomReady) using javascript (which gives you a lot more freedom to choose the best algorithm for the layout you need, but still a usable yet not perfect layout for those few anti-javascript-guys out there).

However, it is hard to tell without seeing the actual markup and requirements.

Comment: thanks, this is helpful info if I end up having to solve the layout with javascript

Answer (score 1):

If absolute positioning is absolutely not an option, you'll need to calculate the height of elements prior to the page generating and put each block into the correct column based on heights. Trust me, absolute positioning is much easier!

You'll probably want something like [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/). It sets up the columns for you as you require. It does rely on absolute positioning, but that's just about your only easy option. You'll need to tinker with the code a little to make it responsive, I did it on an in-development site [here](http://dev.dclcreative.com/tcOutlet/) but I can't entirely remember what I did, sorry. Feel free to look through the source code though.

Masonry is pretty quick; below is the basic setup, [here are more details](http://masonry.desandro.com/).

HTML

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">...</div>
  <div class="item w2">...</div>
  <div class="item">...</div>
  ...
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
var container = document.querySelector('#container');
var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
  // options
  columnWidth: 200,
  itemSelector: '.item'
});
```

Comment: Thanks for responding - I'll keep Masonry in mind in case I can't make it work with CSS on its own

Comment: @cantera25 CS3 columns may be worth looking into as well. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multi-column_layouts

Comment: Something like Masonry is the answer.  The answer will involve JavaScript.  The limitations of the CSS visual formatting model are such that you can't get a three column layout as needed with the markup that you have.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make the following layout with CSS only: http://jsfiddle.net/hpr2b/7/

```
.top-center {
    width: 55%;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px 0 10px 25%;
}

.top-left {
    float: right;
    width: 25%;
    margin: 10px 75% 40px -100%;
}

.top-right {
    float: right;
    width: 20%;
    margin: 10px 0 40px 0;
}

.mid-center {
    margin: 10px 20% 10px 25%;
    clear: left;
}

.mid-left {
    float: left;
    clear: right;
    width: 25%;
    margin-top: -20px;
}

.mid-right {
    float: right;
    clear: right;
    width: 20%;
    margin-top: -20px;
}

.bottom-center {
    margin: 0 20% 10px 25%;
}
```